# Why is my javascript while loop not working?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

My while loop should, on each iteration, create an img tag, set its src, then add an event listener. This event listener fires on error event, which would be a 404, in the case the is not found. The images are stored in a local file, but I don't know how many files might be in each project folder. Images will be named 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. As soon as an error event has fired on one of the img tags, this will mean we have reached the end of the images for a particular project, and this event listener will change isLooping to false, and the while loop should stop executing at this point. However my browser just enters a state of perpetual loading. No errors in the console but browser will eventually crash. Why is this? I think it's a problem with how I have set up my while loop.

```
const GalleryProject = (function () {
  const galleryContainer = document.querySelector('.gallery-container')
  let isLooping = true

  function openProject(index = 1) {
    const imagesContainer = document.createElement('div')
    imagesContainer.classList.add('images-container')

    const bigImgTag = document.createElement('img')
    bigImgTag.classList.add('big')

    const smallImgTagContainer = document.createElement('div')
    smallImgTagContainer.classList.add('small-img-container')

    imagesContainer.appendChild(bigImgTag)
    imagesContainer.appendChild(smallImgTagContainer)
    galleryContainer.appendChild(imagesContainer)

    displayProjectInfo(index)
    loadBigImage(index)
    loadSmallImages(index)
  }

  function loadBigImage(index) {
    const bigImg = document.querySelector('img.big')
    bigImg.src = `assets/projects/single-bucket/${index}/main-image.jpeg`
  }

  const smallImgErrorHandler = function () {
    isLooping = false
    this.remove()
  }

  function loadSmallImages(index) {
    const smallImgContainer = document.querySelector('.small-img-container')
    let i = 1
    while (isLooping) {
      const img = document.createElement('img')
      img.addEventListener('error', smallImgErrorHandler)
      img.src = `assets/projects/single-bucket/${index}/${i}.jpeg`
      smallImgContainer.appendChild(img)
      i++
    }
  }

  function displayProjectInfo(index) {
    const textWrapper = document.createElement('div')
    textWrapper.classList.add('project-description-wrapper')

    const title = document.createElement('p')
    title.classList.add('project-title')
    title.textContent = projectData[index - 1].title

    const description = document.createElement('p')
    description.classList.add('project-description')
    description.textContent = projectData[index - 1].description

    textWrapper.appendChild(title)
    textWrapper.appendChild(description)
    galleryContainer.appendChild(textWrapper)
  }

  return { openProject }
})()

GalleryProject.openProject()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "browser will eventually crash"?

Comment: Just that literally nothing on the page loads. At all. There's a "loading" icon.animation in the browser tab for the page, but no error messages in the console. This continues for a couple minutes before the browser displayed a message: "Aww snap. Something went wrong loading the page. Error code 5". I've retyped this myself, but this is the gist.

Comment: Your approach is interesting in that there likely is never an un-ending or indeterminate number of images to load. Work with the upper-bound limit and solve your issue. If you want them displayed _as they are loaded_ you'll have to take @Alexis's approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to program in JavaScript.

The loading of the images is going to be asynchronous, therefore, you need to wait for the load to be complete before you go on.

In other words, right now, you loop really fast adding new `<img src=.../>` tags without waiting for the image to be loaded or for the load to have failed. You need to do it *asynchronously*. This means create one image tag, wait for either success or failure. On success, try to load the next image. That means your code needs to change dramatically. The "while" loop is replace by these success/failure callbacks instead.

---

**Update based on comments:**

If you can instead get the total number of images for that one run, then having a loop based on that total number will be faster. This is because you'll give the browser all the URLs at once and in most cases it will attempt to load at least two images in parallel.

Comment: My code works in its current form when using a for loop and setting an arbitrary "limit". For example, for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++). Originally I was trying to do this with promises. I'll revisit that approach and see how I get on though. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Alexis - _you need to wait for the load to be complete before you go on._ - not really true in general. For the OP's code sure, but the OP's issue (as you point out) is doing this inside a loop. There is nothing wrong with caching a bunch of images and rendering them all after the cache is filled. But that would require an upper bound to the number of images (as the OP's comment to you points out - and works).